# How to set a var inside a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to set some vars from a dict in a Django template. I access a dict items and values, but when I try to set some value from that, it does not work

This works:

```
{% for key, value in v.items %}
   {% if key == 'title' %}<tr>{{ value }}</tr>{% endif%}
   {% if key == 'name' %}<tr>{{ value }}</tr>{% endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work:

```
{% for key, value in v.items %}
   {% if key == 'title' %}{% with title as value %}{%$ endwith %}{% 
endif%}
   {% if key == 'name' %}{% with name as value %}{%$ endwith %}{% 
endif%}
{% endfor%}
<tr>{{ title }}</tr><tr>{{ name }}</tr>
```

I want to set a VAR inside a django template from a dict value!

Comment: it is because, you are using  `{{title}}` and `{{name}}` outside with tag, variable scope is within the tags only !

Answer (score 0):

`with` is used to define a local context, not "set a var". So as Pankaj said, your variables won't work unless they are within the `{% with ... %}{% endwith %}`

Notice that it should be `with existing_var as new_var_name` and not the other way round. You also don't need `$` to close the tag.

So this would print out the variables (not exactly as you want them but they would show up):

```
{% for key, value in v.items %}
   {% if key == 'title' %}{% with value as title %}{{ title }}{% endwith %}{% 
endif%}
   {% if key == 'name' %}{% with value as name %}{{ name }}{% endwith %}{% 
endif%}
{% endfor%}
```

However, you do not need to do this (and it's a bit pointless to just change the name of a variable). If `v` is a dictionary, why not do:

```
<tr>{{ v.title }}</tr><tr>{{ v.name }}</tr>
```

Generally you shouldn't really be trying to set variables in a Django template. If you need to extract data / perform transformations you should probably do it in your view, or using a template tag.

Comment: Great! Thank you @geekfish

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @geekfish:

```
{% for key, value in v.items %}
    <tr>{{ v.title }}</tr><tr>{{ v.name }}</tr>
{% endfor%}
```

;)